# Sleep function fires twice

Tags: php, sleep

I have 31 rows in my DB and I want to load them with 2 seconds interval. But when sleep function is live for 60 seconds, main function repeats and $count resets.

My code:

```
    $count = 0; 
    $files_count = count($files);
        foreach($files as $file) {
            $count++;
            $bot_file_name = $file['bot_file_name'];
            $bot_file_tg_id = $file['bot_file_tg_id'];
            $bot_file_format = $file['bot_file_format'];
            if ($bot_file_format == "pdf") {
                // do something
            } else if ($bot_file_format == "video") {
                // do something
            } else if ($bot_file_format == "audio") {
                // do something
            }
            if ($count == $files_count) {
                break;
            }
            sleep(2);
        }
```

I can't understand what is wrong here. 
php max_execution_time is 120.

Comment: how you set the `max_execution_time` ?

Comment: What is the value of $files_count ?

Comment: @4givN yes. 120 sec.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld 31.